# What is the real-world difference between Data Centre standard SSDs and consumer SSDs?

Tags: ssd, webserver

We need to update the SSDs on our dedicated server to a RAID pair of 480GB ones.

Our hosts have quoted us a cost for the new hardware, we will increase our monthly lease charge by £35/month extra for the disks so we are spreading the cost over the future. I forecast the drives will last us at least another 4 years. That's £1,680 over 4 years so I understand we are overpaying in the long run but the hosts also guarantee the hardware themselves and we pay less up front.

My boss, upon hearing this, suggested we just go out and just buy our own pair of 480GB SSDs, and then only pay the hosts for installation. He has recently fitted SSDs in to all his computers and says from researching they're "all the same".

I don't know enough about enterprise-grade hardware to know whether data-centre and consumer SSDs are "all the same". What is the difference, realistically speaking?

The server application is probably 70% reads, 30% writes, at an estimate.

Answer (score 1):

There are few important differences between enterprise and consumer SSDs, that can be quite important.

- Enterprise SSDs normally have some kind of power buffer, that keeps the SSD powered long enough to complete outstanding writes in case the server should lose all power. This avoids incomplete writes and possible data corruption.
- Enterprise SSDs usually have a different type of flash cells, that store the actual data. Most, if not all, consumer SSDs have MLC cells or some derivative of that. Enterprise SSDs have SLC or a very durable variant of MLC. Technically the effect is that consumer SSDs store more information in each flash cell, which allows for more storage for the same cash, but at the price that flash degrades faster and the SSDs fail quicker. So you might be able to write 10x more data on a enterprise SSD before it fails.
- Also a enterprise SSD is designed for continous 24/7 use while a consumer SSD usually is normally designed for only 8 hours or so daily use, which also might lead to quicker failure

Aside from the differences you also want to make sure, that you use two different SSD models in the mirror. Otherwise you might run into the nasty problem, that both SSDs have the same endurance. Then when one fails, the other quickly follows, maybe even before you can replace the failed drive, leading to data loss even in a mirrored setup.

Answer (score 1):

### Differences are:

- Intended market/usage. Enterprise drives are meant to be on 24/7 and 
  can usually withstand higher temperatures or other stresses. Consumer
  grade drives are expected to be on 8-10 hours a day or so. Lifespan
  and MTBF are based off these expectations.
- Features included/supported by firmware. Enterprise drives may have
  more intelligent wear-leveling, better error-checking, and 'smarter'
  firmware in general. Enterprise drives may also have a larger
  capacity of spare overhead to deal with failed blocks. Consumer grade
  drives will have a stripped down or more basic firmware.
- Component/construction. Enterprise drives will usually be made of
  longer-lasting flash memory, and will use different architectures
  that may be constructed to optimize performance in specific
  workloads. Consumer grade drives will be made of cheaper components.
- Warranty and support. Enterprise drives have better warranties and
  better support, allowing customers things like next-day replacement
  and advance RMA. Consumer grade drives will usually only be replaced
  via an RMA process where you do not have a replacement for several
  weeks.
- Hardware level support, QVLs. Enterprise grade drives will be tested
  & vetted, and will be guaranteed to work in particular platforms.
  Consumer grade drives will be expected to work in consumer grade
  computers, and are not vetted for other platforms.
- In general, if: 1.) you are very comfortable with supporting your own    hardware,and 2.) you have a good understanding of how to avoid data
  loss through redundancy/backups, then there is no real problem with
  using consumer grade gear.

Now you know the differences, here's my opinion.

**Should I use consumer grade SSD drives or should I use enterprise grade SSD drives?**

Enterprise grade without a doubt! Why? Enterprise Grade drives have a higher endurance level, they contain power loss data protection features and they consistently provide high level of performance. All align with a strategy ensuring reliable and consistent performance.